# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wpcf7

Tags: fatal-error

I need help on how to fix Fatal error.
It happened when i downloaded the contact form 7 plugin and when i clicked the activate buttton the message below pop out. This message prevent me from accessing the backend of my website.

Please i really need help.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wpcf7_add_shortcode() in /home3/africsis/public_html/bethelbright/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7-simple-hidden-field/cf7-simple-hidden-field.php:30 Stack trace: #0 /home3/africsis/public_html/bethelbright/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(298): wpcf7_simple_hidden_field->init('') #1 /home3/africsis/public_html/bethelbright/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(323): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #2 /home3/africsis/public_html/bethelbright/wp-includes/plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #3 /home3/africsis/public_html/bethelbright/wp-settings.php(325): do_action('plugins_loaded') #4 /home3/africsis/public_html/bethelbright/wp-config.php(93): require_once('/home3/africsis...') #5 /home3/africsis/public_html/bethelbright/wp-load.php(37): require_once('/home3/africsis...') #6 /home3/africsis/public_html/bethelbright/wp-admin/admin.php(31): require_once('/home3/africsis...') #7 /home3/africsis/public_html/bethelbright/wp-admin/index.php(10): require_once('/home3/africs in /home3/africsis/public_html/bethelbright/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7-simple-hidden-field/cf7-simple-hidden-field.php on line 30

Comment: Add error message to tag <code>

Answer (score 1):

To disable the plugin you can log into cPanel or into the installation folder via FTP and rename or remove the plugin folder in /wp-content/plugins/ - Once you've done this you should be able to login to the dashboard without any issues.

There is possibly a conflict between the current theme and the Contact Form 7 plugin that you are trying to use. Maybe try an alternative contact form plugin like Gravity Forms and see if you have the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

wpcf7_add_shortcode is deprecated since Contact Form 7 version 4.6! Use wpcf7_add_form_tag instead:

http://contactform7.com/2016/12/03/contact-form-7-46/
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/issue-wpcf7_add_shortcode-is-deprecated-after-update/

Can you please update your plugin?

Also deprecated :

WPCF7_Shortcode

WPCF7_ShortcodeManager

wpcf7_add_shortcode()

wpcf7_scan_shortcode()

Comment: He is obviously using the latest version of the plugin but his theme isn't compatible as it contains the depreciated shortcodes. He should attempt to update the theme once regaining access to the dashboard.